# convert ruby cucumber to protractor-cucumber

Tags: ruby, protractor, cucumber

Is there is any tooling out there to convert a ruby cucumber test script to protractorjs?  I want to try out a new tool, but need a way to convert ruby cucumber to protractorjs.

Comment: A keyboard would probably be the best tool for this. There is honestly no functional way to do this as ruby and javascript live in different worlds and serve very different purposes

Comment: They both serve the same purpose in this case (running cucumber tests) but I understand they live in different worlds... I just wasn't sure if a translator has been built or not.

Comment: `cucumber-ruby` is written using ruby language and `protractor-cucumber` is written using node.js (javascript language). Though there are tools to convert ruby to javascript like - http://opalrb.org/. I think its not worth the time. Instead start afresh with writing your scripts using protractor.js & cucumber.js which are built using node.js